# I just cant get my j2me tools to work on opensuse!

Tags: java, opensuse

am trying to install and use j2me tools on my new opensuse box, but I've tried both the rpm and *.bin approaches and neither works!

When I use yast to install the downloaded `sun_java_wireless_toolkit-2.5.2-1.1.i586.rpm`
, the installation process shows success, but when I try to look for the wireless kit from my dev tools I cant find it.

Anybody with a clue?

Comment: 1. Define "not working".   2. Improve the title of your question.

Comment: I've voted to move this to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com), since that site is more suited for questions about installing and running programs.